# Why is this number a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, typeof

Using the jQuery Cookies plugin, I am setting a cookie, the value of which is a number.

```
$.cookie('xyz_id','1');
```

I need to use this number to get the index of an element in my HTML.

```
var $curr = $.cookie('xyz_id'); 
var $el = $('#main li:eq($curr)');
```

The output of $curr is 1. So why does the typeOf() $curr show as a string instead of a number? My attempts to convert it to a number using parseInt() have failed. Not sure what's going on....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quotes make a variable a string:

```
'1'
```

However, in this case, cookies are effectively strings:

> To read out a cookie you have to treat
>   document.cookie as a string and search
>   for certain characters (semicolons,
>   for instance) and for the cookie name.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Instead, do:

```
$.cookie('xyz_id', 1); // or, really, '1' would be the same
```

Then, when reading the value back, cast it back to a numeric value using `parseInt()`.

```
var xyz_id = parseInt($.cookie('xyz_id'));
```

Which should create a numeric value.

Also, `parseInt` should work (within reason) for typecasting a number from a string. See:

```
var i = "1";
alert(typeof i);
i = parseInt(i);
alert(typeof i);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CqBw6/

Comment: As I have said in an other answer below, always use the radix parameter with `parseInt`, it's just a bad practice to leave Javascript guess the base of the number you are trying to parse.

Comment: Fortunately this is a universal truth. Languages like ruby/js/python etc will have the same issues. You can always console.log the output with firebug and see the type of the object.

Comment: For some reason removing the quotes from the $.cookie's value parameter still returns it as a string, not sure why...

Comment: @Jared: No. The quotes make `'1'` a string, but this has nothing directly to do with why cookie values are always returned as strings. (However, casting back is correct. :D)

Comment: @Tomalak - So you're saying that document.cookie returns only string values?

Comment: @Adam - I added some additional information following Tomalak's comment. @Tomalak - Let me know if this is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseInt(str,10)` as others have suggested.

You should also use string concatenation when building your selector:

```
var $el = $('#main li:eq('+$curr+')');
```

It's also good practice for consistency and code readability to only use `$something` variable names for jQuery objects, not strings or numbers.

Comment: Or even better, never use $ names.  Especially if your backend is in PHP (I learned that the hard way one time... 5000 lines of classic javascript, subsequently coupled with PHP and then jQuery... urk).

Comment: Oh, and +1 for making sure to use the radix for parseInt.

Answer (score 1):

This in fact has very little to do with the fact that you passed a numeric *string* to the jQuery cookie plugin, because even if you'd passed a literal `1`, it wouldn't have remained non-string for very long!

Cookie values are stored internally, essentially, as strings. The value goes into HTTP headers and through to the end-user's browser and, as such, are far removed from the Javascript type system.

Fortunately, since Javascript is dynamically-typed, it shouldn't matter. If the value is numeric in representation, you are free to cast it back to a numeric type:

```
var value = $.cookie('name');
alert(parseInt(value, 10)); // note: specify the radix!
```

Still, I wouldn't bother, since you're going to be concatenating it straight back into a string:

```
var $el = $('#main li:eq(' + value + ')');
```

Or, to make use of efficiency in modern browsers, you can do:

```
var $el = $('#main li').eq(parseInt(value, 10)); // I recommend this version
```

---

There's a clue in [the plugin's source](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt):

```
document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
```

and

```
cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
```

Cookie name/value pairs are all "strings".

Comment: Thanks for the great cookie explanation

Answer (score 0):

The answers above do solve the issue here of saving a string to a cookie instead of an integer.  You can also coerce strings into integers and vice versa.

```
parseInt('1'); //1
```

you can check if an integer is really created with `isNaN()`

```
var n = parseInt('1');
if( !isNaN( n ) ){
  //Horray we have an integer
}
```

Comment: Please always use the radix parameter on `parseInt`. This is just a bad practice not to do so. `parseInt("1", 10)` is the proper way to do so.

Comment: Yes 10 would prevent it from accidently treating the string as hexadecimal or octal, but it wouldn't prevent it from removing characters in a string with numbers and characters in it.  So I wouldn't say leaving off 10 is a bad practice, and it doesn't cover all the things that can go wrong when using parseInt.  There's many gotchas with this function

Comment: That including the radix parameter doesn't solve every problem, ever, is not a good reason to dispute that you ought _always_ to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. My original difficulty was due to the fact that I didn't properly place the parseInt() in the $curr variable. duh.

It's odd though - I wonder why removing the quotes from the second parameter still returns a string.

```
$.cookie('xyz_id', 2);
```

or

```
$.cookie('xyz_id', '2');
```

both return strings.

Comment: They don't return strings. They do result in strings being returned by an eventual call to `$.cookie('xyz_id')`. :)

Answer (score -3):

I think you should change `$.cookie('xyz_id','1');` to `$.cookie('xyz_id',1);`, and if it's still a string, you can used eval() to make it a number.

[x]

Comment: Use parseInt() to turn a string formatted like this into a number.  Use eval() as a last resort only.